# Arithmetic right shift not working in Verilog HDL

Tags: verilog, logical-operators, bit-shift

I am building a shift-unit that is capable of arithmetic and logical right shift, and logical left shift depending on the control signals given to it. However, the arithmetic right shift operator output generates output similar to that logical right shift operator, i.e. sign extension does not occur.

Main code

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module shift_unit(
    input [15:0] a,
    input [3:0] b,
     input clk,
    input isLSL,
    input isLSR,
    input isASR,
    output reg [15:0] result
    );
wire [15:0] LSL_result, LSR_result, ASR_result;

LSL lsl(a, b, clk, isLSL, LSL_result);
LSR lsr(a, b, clk, isLSR, LSR_result);
ASR asr(a, b, clk, isASR, ASR_result);

always@(posedge clk) begin
case({isLSL, isLSR, isASR})
    3'b001: result <= ASR_result;
    3'b010: result <= LSR_result;
    3'b100: result <= LSL_result;
endcase
end

endmodule
```

LSL code:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module LSL(
    input [15:0] a,
    input [3:0] b,
     input clk,
     input isLSL,
    output [15:0] out
    );

reg [15:0] result;
always@(posedge clk) begin
    if(isLSL)   result = a << b;
end
assign out = result;

endmodule
```

LSR code:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module LSR(
    input [15:0] a,
    input [3:0] b,
    input clk,
    input isLSR,
    output [15:0] out
    );

reg [15:0] result;
always@(posedge clk) begin
    if(isLSR)   result = a >> b;
end
assign out = result;

endmodule
```

ASR code:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module ASR(
    input [15:0] a,
    input [3:0] b,
    input clk,
    input isASR,
    output [15:0] out
    );

reg [15:0] result;
always@(posedge clk) begin
    if(isASR)   result = a >>> b;
end
assign out = result;

endmodule
```

And finally, the testbench:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module shift_unit_test;
    reg [15:0] a;
    reg [3:0] b;
    reg clk;
    reg isLSL;
    reg isLSR;
    reg isASR;

    wire [15:0] result;

    shift_unit uut (
        .a(a), 
        .b(b), 
        .clk(clk), 
        .isLSL(isLSL), 
        .isLSR(isLSR), 
        .isASR(isASR), 
        .result(result)
    );

    always #5 clk = ~clk;

    initial begin
        clk = 1'b0;
        a = 16'b1100101011001010;
        b = 4;
        {isLSL, isLSR, isASR} = 3'b100; #100;
        {isLSL, isLSR, isASR} = 3'b010; #100;
        {isLSL, isLSR, isASR} = 3'b001; #100;
    end

endmodule
```

The above code has been modelled using Xilinx ISE 14.7.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be working with `signed` signals to get sign extension.

```
module ASR(
    input wire signed [15:0] a,
    input [3:0] b,
    input clk,
    input isASR,
    output reg signed [15:0] out
    );


always@(posedge clk) begin
    if(isASR)   out = a >>> b;
end

endmodule
```